# How to convert Perl regular expression into Python?

Tags: python, regex, perl, python-3.x

How do you convert this Perl regular expression into Python:

```
(?:

    ^(?:never|no|nothing|nowhere|noone|none|not|
        havent|hasnt|hadnt|cant|couldnt|shouldnt|
        wont|wouldnt|dont|doesnt|didnt|isnt|arent|aint
    )$

)

|

n't
```

Comment: Go to http://pythex.org and test out the regex. It's the fastest way to find out if particular syntax of your regex will work or not.

Answer (score 4):

That expression will work *as is* in Python. Just use the [`re.VERBOSE` switch](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.X) or remove all the whitespace.

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> pattern = re.compile('''\
... (?:
... 
...     ^(?:never|no|nothing|nowhere|noone|none|not|
...         havent|hasnt|hadnt|cant|couldnt|shouldnt|
...         wont|wouldnt|dont|doesnt|didnt|isnt|arent|aint
...     )$
... 
... )
... 
... |
... 
... n't
... ''', flags=re.VERBOSE)
>>> pattern.match('never').group()
'never'
>>> pattern.match('wouldnt').group()
'wouldnt'
```